# Can I set a basic block's parent in IDA?

Tags: ida

I got a function whose control flow is kinda screwed... like this:

[image]

As you can see, the basic blocks at the top left aren't connected to anything; however, if I check the text disasm, this is what I see:

[image]

As you can see, IDA believes that the call doesn't ever return, puts the discontinued line there, and the control flow gets broken (as the next basic block doesn't have a parent).

Is there any way I can manually link the basic blocks, or better, make IDA stop believing that the call doesn't return?

**EDIT**:
The function *does* return, and doesn't break the rest of places it's used:

[image]

Comment: Could you give trying to *reanalyze program* a go? That's at options -> General -> Analysis -> reanalyze program

Comment: have you figured this out?

Comment: @Krypton haven't done it myself but I heard it can be done with the cpp SDK

Answer (score 2):

The following picture shows a similar case (Ida V6.3):

[image]

with the corresponding useless graph view:
[image]

Obviously, Ida is completely disturbed.
What worked for me in this case, was the following simple procedure:

1. Undefine Function and code => Ida will show the byte code only
2. Select the whole undefined area and re-define as code ("C"-key)
3. Re-define as function.

Thre resulting graph view now looks decent:
[image]

This helped here, it might however not be a remedy in all similar cases.

**Remark**: In this particular case, undefining and re-defining the function without undefining the code as well did NOT work.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to define a function as "return" or "no return".

To do it you should find your called function, right click on it, choose "edit function" and unmark "Does not return" checkbox.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that, but the function isn't marked as 'Does not return'. I edited the post btw

Comment: May be it is one of functions which is called by your not returning function ?

Comment: But the function *does* return, it's just a `printf` like function which **returns** a pointer to a formatted string instead of printing it to stdout, so I'm really sure it can't be that it's 'not returning'

Comment: I'd be glad to see a binary if possible. It is really strange.

Comment: BTW, do you get something interesting if you patch this call with nops ?

Comment: I don't have the binary, I only have the IDB, which I cannot share. It's a Black Ops 3 Beta dump anyway, so you can check that if you have the game... about nopping out the call: it doesn't change anything, the graph stays the same

Answer (score 1):

Uhm... you could do the other way around. Try this: in the address of the basic block that should be connected from that call statement you say, press Alt+F11 (change callee) and put the address where the call statement is.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the type of function *va*(using hotkey Y). Then if that has no effect, you can try to undefine the function, and re-define that func to force IDA re-analyse.

If you have HexRays decompiler, you can call the decompiler in this function and then click into function *va*, and then return to the original function.

Those above are tricks for IDA to force the analysis to be launched.
I have testeds them on binaries of different CTFs. And in most siturations they worked.

P.S.:Sorry for my poor English